# Handling multiple futures in Build

Tags: flutter

This is my build:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Position>(
        future: _init,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          ...
          final Position position = snapshot.data!;
          return FlutterMap(
            ...
            layers: [
              ...
              MarkerLayerOptions(
                markers: markers, //this is the future list
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
      }
```

Now, markers is a Future and I build it with this methods:

```
late Future<List<Marker>> markers;

@override
  void initState() {
    ...
    markers = getMarkers();
  }

Future<List<Marker>> getMarkers() async {
   List<Marker> markerTemp = [];
   for (var friend in friendsList) {
     DocumentSnapshot document = await locationRef.doc(friend).get();
     if (document.exists) 
         markerTemp.add(Marker(...));
   }
   return markerTemp;
}
```

So when I run my application I get an error saying that markers is not initialized. How can I have my list ready when called in the build method?

I tried things like nested FutureBuilder or using Future.wait([item1,item2]) but since I'm newbie to this language I'm having troubles implementing it the right way probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using FutureBuilder in some way similar to this:

```
return FutureBuilder<List<Marker>>(
          future: markers,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");

            // You can access the list here, use this newly created list
            List<Markers> markerList = snapshot.data as List<Marker>;
            return FutureBuilder<Position>(...)
          });
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe `FutureBuilder` will solve your problem. try this:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    initialData: null,
    future: Future.wait(getMarkers()),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      ...
    },
  );
}
```

it's that simple. if something goes wrong just make sure your `getMarkers()` actually return a list of Futures and you'll be alright

Comment: I still have the same error, can you please put your complete Build suggestion?

Comment: your function must return a list of futures, not a future list